# Highcharts long labels

Tags: highcharts, label

I have a question about long labels in highcharts.

If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/xeHyB/ you can see there very long labels, what makes that long labels are visible and chart in very small - useless.

```
 xAxis: {
            categories: ['Bla bla bla label, bla bla Bla bla bla label, bla bla Bla bla bla label Bla bla bla label, bla ', 'Bla bla bla label, bla bla', 'Bla bla bla label, bla bla', 'Bla bla bla label Bla bla bla label, bla bla Bla bla bla label, bla bla, bla bla', 'Bla bla bla label, bla bla', 'Bla bla bla label, bla bla']
        },
```

I would like that labels would be short and elipsis and chart would be bigger,but on the tooltip I would like to see entire label.

Is that even possible?

Best Reagrds Matej

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [label formatter function](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) option to format the labels any way you want:

```
       xAxis: {
            categories: ['Bla bla bla label, bla bla Bla bla bla label, bla bla Bla bla bla label Bla bla bla label, bla ', 'Bla bla bla label, bla bla', 'Bla bla bla label, bla bla', 'Bla bla bla label Bla bla bla label, bla bla Bla bla bla label, bla bla, bla bla', 'Bla bla bla label, bla bla', 'Bla bla bla label, bla bla'],
            labels:{
                formatter: function(){
                    if (this.value.length > 10){
                        return this.value.substr(0,10) + "...";
                    }else{
                         return this.value;   
                    }                        
                }
            }
        },
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xeHyB/2/).